# Set the "-x" slewing option for NTP startup

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

On RedHat it can be set in `/etc/sysconfig/ntpd` but despite much searching on web and also reading `man` page for ntpd, I cannot find how you do this on Ubuntu (set `-x` option on ntpd).

I can manually kill ntpd on Ubuntu and then set it by re-launching ntpd manually, i.e.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -x -u 128:138
```

but I'd like these settings to take effect at startup on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

According to a bug report (Debian [#415335 ntp: Allow to set the time in slewed mode upon installation.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=415335)), this is done by a configuration tweak:

> You can already do this by editing `/etc/default/ntp` and adding
>   `-x` to the `NTPD_OPTS`.